# Pull Stock Symbols from Excel file instead of hard coding the symbols

Tags: python, excel

I currently have code where I'm hard coding stock symbols in the line below.

response = c.get_quotes(['META','AAPL','CAT','GOOG'])

Instead of hard coding the symbols, I want to pull them from column A in an excel file.

Column A

[image]

I'm pretty sure I would need this line below. Could someone tell me what other code I would need to have the symbols flow into the code line above to replace the hard coded symbols?  Thanks

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test.xlsm', sheet_name='Sheet1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `df` dataframe to extract the stock symbols from column `A` and pass them as a list to the `get_quotes` method.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test.xlsm', sheet_name='Sheet1')
symbols = df['A'].tolist()

response = c.get_quotes(symbols)
```

Comment: Excellent, sure appreciate your help!